# Cookie Notice Keeps Reappearing - Magento 2.3.7

Tags: magento2, cookie, allow-cookie

Since updating my store to 2.3.7 have noticed the cookie notice intermittently showing up randomly before the expiry date has passed. Get this often when I save on backend then revisit a page however not necessarily, it may take 3 days or as low as a few mins before I see it again.

The `user_allowed_save_cookie` seems to be unset when this happens however my cookie seems to be set correctly prior to this with domain seemingly ok (.www.domain.com) and expires a year from now.

Only a few cookies set on site so feel am hitting no browser limits or anything like that and wondering if this has been experienced by anyone else that may know cause / solution for this?

Site uses varnish, is multi-store, redis sessions however not quite sure how to debug and find the cause for this issue at present.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your cookie default settings? We need to give the right cookie path and domain information to ensure all the cookie related information are working well in multi-store configuration.